# Using .format() to line up strings

Tags: python, string

I need to get the asterix lines to all lineup together only using the .format() function. So far I can only get them to move away from the titles on the same line. I need to get the first asterix from each string to line up. Sorry for the noob question.

```
index = 0
choice_titles = ['Steal:','Deal:','Comp Steal:','Comp Deal:']
choice_counts = [3, 7, 4, 6]

print('Game Stats: \n')

while index < len(choice_counts):
    (format(choice_titles[index], '<10s'))
    print(choice_titles[index], end='  ' )

    asterix_Disp = ''.join('*' for number in range(0, choice_counts[index]))
    (format(asterix_Disp, '>10s'))
    print(asterix_Disp)

    index += 1
```

Comment: Can you add how the expected output look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get them to line up, you need to make sure that the titles are printed with the same length.  `'Comp Steal:'` is 11 characters long, so your format should be at least that much, 10 is not enough. Make it at least 12 or so.

Furthermore, `format()` returns a string that is formatted to that specification.  You don't do anything with it.  I guess you wanted to print it.

```
print(format(choice_titles[index], '12s'), end='  ')
```

You don't need to format the asterisks since they're at the end.  It won't throw off the alignment on anything else.  Just print it out.  p.s., to repeat a character `n` times, just multiply the character by `n`. What you have there is unnecessarily complicated.

```
print('*' * choice_counts[index])
```

Comment: This has worked and it looks much cleaner! Thank you, your a legend!